# How to change display function based on select options chosen?

Tags: javascript, html, function, select

I have a problem with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Q3</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function showvar(x) {
            let sum = 0;
            let ssq=0;
            let N = x.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

                sum = sum + x[i];
                ssq+=x[i]*x[i];

            }
            let variance=(ssq-sum*sum/N)/(N-1)
            return variance;

        }

        function showsd(x) {
            let sum = 0;
            let ssq=0;
            let N = x.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

                sum = sum + x[i];
                ssq+=x[i]*x[i];

            }
            let variance=(ssq-sum*sum/N)/(N-1)

            let sd=Math.sqrt(variance)
            return sd;
        }

        function display() {
            let numbers = document.getElementById("numbers").value.split(" ");

            for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                numbers[i] = parseFloat(numbers[i]);
            }
            let v = showvar(numbers);
            let sd = showsd(numbers);
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "variance = " + v;
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Standard deviation = " + sd;


        }


    </script>


</head>
<body>
<p>
    <br><br>
</p>

<input type="text" id="numbers">
<select>
    <option>Standard deviation</option>
    <option>variance</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="display()">Calculate</button>
<p id="display">answer goes here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to make it so that the paragraph will display the correct value based on the option that is selected. So, for example, if I put in some numbers and choose variance, then it will show me the value for variance. I currently just have code for each different option, but I need to somehow put it together. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you are spliting the value `let numbers = document.getElementById("numbers").value.split(" ");` ?

Comment: @YashMaheshwari I'm sorry about that. I did some copy/pasting from other code and forgot to get rid of that. Thanks so much for your help! I was having a hard time with if/else syntax myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your display function to add an if condition:

```
function display() {
            let numbers = document.getElementById("numbers").value.split(" ");

            for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                numbers[i] = parseFloat(numbers[i]);
            }
            if(document.getElementById("options").value === "variance") {
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "variance = " + showvar(numbers);
            } else {
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Standard deviation = " + showsd(numbers);
            }
        }
```

Also add an id to the `select` tag:

```
<select id="options">
    <option>Standard deviation</option>
    <option>variance</option>
</select>
```